# How to install Twig (PHP) on Windows (WAMP server)?

Tags: php, windows, templates, installation, twig

How can i install the templating engine Twig for PHP on a WAMP server please ?
On their website they say i should download a .dll (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html#id1), but their link doesn't work, and i can't find much about this on google.
Thanks for your help :)

PS : It's a windows 7 if it matters.

Comment: Come on, cowards. Who voted to close and why? This seems like a legit question to me.

Comment: Linux gurus who spit on anything that isn't linuxish i guess.

Comment: This looks like a fit for SuperUsers and not StackOverflow. That's probably why it was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment to @Theodore's post I just wanted to check (but don't yet have the rep to comment)...

...do you realise that you do **not** need a DLL in order to use or 'develop' twig applications / twig code?

Twig is just a library that you include in your project source code, usually via composer or by unpacking an archive file. The DLL is just an accellerator to make the twig compiler faster. It's optional and definitely *not* needed just to code up twig templates.

Basically you should follow one of the installation methods on the twig site http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html#installation (composer is what all the cool kids use, but the tar works too)

Once you have a local copy of the files just add a line like this to your code:

```
require_once '/path/to/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
```

And then you're good to go.

Comment: This code sample is written AFTER the installation instructions, which, in a normal human brain, implies that you already have been able to do one of the installation procedures before you can use that code sample. Do you REALLY think i would have wasted my time asking a question here without first having a lookat the twig web site ? I'm not stupid.

Comment: OK - I was just trying to help and sincerely apologise if I offended you. It was unclear what situation you were in and I was confused by your suggestion that you set up a dual-boot *just* to develop twig (it seems a little extreme since twig works fine in windows, albeit without the dll).

Answer (score 0):

Custom Windows DLLs for non-hugely popular PHP extensions (everything except Xdebug, APC, etc.) are usually very hard to come by. They require, usually, MS Visual Studio, a lot of know-how, and usually quite a bit of tinkering with the extension code, which many times has never been compiled for the target version of PHP on Windows, or never before on Windows for any version.

I've done it, and offered my services in the past, but people on SO have downvoted me to hell just for explaining this sad state of affairs.  I've never been able to compile an extension via Visual Studio Express, either.

So it requires hundreds of dollars worth of software *for each targeted compilation and version of PHP* (E.g. Wamp and Z-Wamp use different Visual Studios, even for the same versions), and probably 3-8 hours worth of work.

Mix that in with a culture that balks at pros charging just $250-500 for guaranteed results, and you'll see why windows extension are so rare, and increasingly more so.

Just look at the Xdebug windows download page.
http://xdebug.org/download.php

Here are the ones they support. Each "VC" is a different Visual Studio install. Each package requires different extension code tweaks, compilations, etc.

1. PHP 5.2 VC6 (32 bit)
2. PHP 5.2 VC6 TS (32 bit)
3. PHP 5.2 VC9 (32 bit)
4. PHP 5.2 VC9 TS (32 bit)
5. PHP 5.3 VC9 (64 bit)
6. PHP 5.3 VC9 (32 bit)
7. PHP 5.3 VC9 TS (64 bit)
8. PHP 5.3 VC9 TS (32 bit)
9. PHP 5.4 VC9 (64 bit)
10. PHP 5.4 VC9 (32 bit)
11. PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (64 bit)
12. PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (32 bit)
13. PHP 5.5 VC11 (64 bit)
14. PHP 5.5 VC11 (32 bit)
15. PHP 5.5 VC11 TS (64 bit)
16. PHP 5.5 VC11 TS (32 bit)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not a linux guy so i usually develop on windows with notepad++ and i was hoping not to have to install a linux in dual boot and a LAMP server to use Twig. I'm coding for windows OSs at work, so i know their visual studios are a pain in the ass :)